# Combine discrete uniform distributions to achieve a discrete uniform distribution of a larger range?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

How can I effectively combine multiple discrete uniform distributions of a limited range to achieve a discrete uniform distribution of a large range? I.e. given $unif\{a,b\}$ generate $unif\{a,c\}, c>b$.

As an example, say I have a 37-sided die (dice), but really need uniform values from 1 to 59.  (Primes chosen intentionally.)  Obviously summing multiple values to match or extend beyond the desired range (modulus the desired range) would result in a Gaussian distribution.

My CS-based approach is to convert the original to a binary function, and apply repeatedly to generate a binary number in the desired range (discarding exceptional values in each stage).  For my example, treat 1-18 as zero, 19-36 as one, and discard 37; repeat 6 times to generate a 6-digit binary, add 1, discarding resultant values 60-64.  Obviously the logical extension to this is to divide the original range into multiple bits, i.e. generate $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$ bits for each value in the original $n$ range.

My question essentially, is there a better, more mathematically-sound approach?

Comment: From the first paragraph, I thought you are talking about continuous uniform distributions. From the dice example it seems you're interested in discrete uniform. Please clarify which. Approaches would be different.

Comment: Discrete.  Please excuse my math gibberish as I'm obviously not a mathematician.  Incidentally I did write "discrete" in the title and twice in the first comment line...

Comment: I don't think the following is "more mathematical" but your computer might be happy with it: if $x\in[1,37]$ take $y=\dfrac{58(x-1)}{36}+1$ ... but it works with continuous uniform, and you need discrete (and rounding to the nearest integer won't help, unless you devise a rounding method that would round e.g. $1.3$ down to $1$ with probability $0.7$ and up to $2$ with probability $0.3$ ... so you could make this work in the discrete case too).

Comment: Maybe something like this: Two 37-sided dice, one red one green. If both even or both odd, use 1-30 from red die; otherwise use 1-30 plus 30 from green die. If either die higher than 30 or you don't get a number 1-59, start over. I suppose this would average fewer than 6 rolls per usable number.

Comment: to follow up on the idea from my previous comment, rounding needs to be done more carefully and won't work well if neighboring values are too far apart (e.g. if you would want to go from $37$ to say $757$ instead of $59$). But perhaps, when trying to go from $37$ to $59$ you need not repeat 6 times (but only 2). If $p,q$ each is integer in $[1,37]$ then $z=37p+q$ is uniform in $[74,1406]$. Then $w=\dfrac{58(z-74)}{1332}+1$ is uniform in $[1,59]$ but takes non-integer values, so would need to be corrected with appropriately randomized rounding up or down, the details of which I did not verify.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I'll assume that the numbers on the dice start with $0$.

Roll the $37$-sided die twice, with results $a$ and $b$, and calculate $37a+b$. Repeat until you get a number below $23\cdot59=1357$ (the highest multiple of $59$ below $37^2=1369$). Then use $37a+b\bmod 59$. The expected number of rolls required is $\frac2{1357/1369}=\frac{2738}{1357}\approx2.02$.